# Copying a string into an empty string without using a lib function

Tags: c++, stack, c-strings

I'm trying to copy a string **p** into an empty string **stack** using a function **push**. I don't wanna use any other function like strcpy or concat.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int tos=0;

void push(char *stack, char c)
{
    stack[tos++]=c;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    char p[]="([]}";
    char stack[]="";

    for(i=0;i<strlen(p);i++)
        push(stack,p[i]);
    
    cout<<"length="<<strlen(stack)<<"\n";

    cout<<stack;
    
    return 0;
}
```

But the output comes out to be

```
length=5
([]}}
```

I don't understand why the length of the new string **stack** comes out to be **5** when the original string it was copied from has a length of **4**. Also, why is the last character **}** repeated at the end of **stack** in output?

Comment: Which is the size of `stack`? greater than the one of `p`?

Comment: This ought to be tagged C, except for the `cout`.

Comment: It's an empty string at first, but after copying 'p' into it, I expected it to be the same size as 'p'. But the output shows its size to be 1 more than that of 'p'

Comment: `char stack[]="";` and then accessing index 1 or greater is Undefined Behaviour.  Also even if `stack` was large enough you forgot to append the trailing `0`.

Comment: No I'm using a Cpp compiler

Comment: I suppose [just doing this](https://ideone.com/shFyXr) is off the radar of whatever the assignment restrictions are.

Comment: @JackStevens the comment from Richard Critten is crucial to understand your issue. You cannot trust any output from your program.

Comment: @RichardCritten thanks I got it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're found out why C++ is so much easier, with `std::string`. Doing this manually, the old-fashioned way is fraught with dangers. The new way is just `stack = p;` Literally, it's that simple.

`stack` is not an "empty string" in your code. It's a `char[1]`. You **cannot** copy any characters into it, because that one char is needed to hold the `\0`. C arrays, unlike `std::string` have a fixed length.

Comment: The thing is I require it to copy one char at a time from the `p` to `stack` so I can't use `stack = p;`

Comment: "You cannot copy any characters into it," --> Code can copy any single character to it - yet like you suggest, it is not big enough for any more like what is needed for `"([]}"`.

Comment: Which part of "`stack` is a `char[1]` so it can't hold more than one `char`" is unclear?

Comment: @JackStevens: Even if you'd need that, modern C++ is much easier. `for (char c:p) stack += c;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate the `stack` variable for instance using `malloc`;

```cpp
int main()
{
    int i;
    char p[]="([]}";
    char* stack;
    stack=(char*)malloc((strlen(p)+1)*sizeof(char));
    
    int len = strlen(p);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
         push(stack,p[i]);
    }

    // if you use char*, you need to end it with `\0`
    push(stack, '\0');
    cout<<"length="<<strlen(stack)<<"\n";

    cout<<stack;
    //do not forget to deallocate
    free(stack);
    return 0;
}
```

You need to allocate the necessary space to be used on stack before using it in C. Indeed, at compile-time, the compiler cannot know, what size you would like to store in the `stack` variable.

The ouput would then be

```sh
length=4
([]}
```

Comment: I still can't understand why is it necessary to do it this way.

Comment: @JackStevens: It shows  how hard this used to be before `std::string`. This answer is wrong- the malloc must be for `strlen(p)+1`, and the loop too. Currently the string copied is unterminated, and the strlen(stack) is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @JackStevens it isnt necessary. With `std::string` it is as simple as `a = b;`. The complications only come with your requirements of doing it the hard way

Comment: Yeah, in general `strlen(p+1)` is `strlen(p)-1`, except when `strlen(p)==0` in which case `strlen(p+1)` is Undefined Behavior. You might notice a certain pattern here with old-style C code.

Comment: Great comments and critics. Thank you for your corrections @MSalters and @ largest_prime_is_463035818

Comment: Also, note that `strlen(p)` is an O(N) function. Calling it in a for-loop is a classic mistake. This is well-defined behavior, just very slow. See https://wiki.c2.com/?ShlemielThePainter

Comment: @MSalters A good compiler can recognize the `p` is not changed and emit efficient code rather than a repeated trip down `strlen(p)`. Still `for(size_t i=0;p[i];i++)` or the like is better.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: An exceptionally good compiler, perhaps. The compiler would need to recognize that `stack` does not alias `p`. This can't be recognized via their types, because `char*` can alias anything. There's a reason C99 has _Restrict

Answer (score 1):

You declared a character array with one element with the value `'\0'`

```
char stack[]="";
```

Arrays have fixed sizes that can not be changed during their lives.

So either you need to use a standard container or container adapter (you could use for example `std::stack<char>` or `std::string`) or you need to allocate memory for elements of the stack yourself. Otherwise your program has undefined behavior because the memory beyond the array stack is being overwritten.

As for your approach then it should simulate something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

size_t top = 0;

void push( char * &stack, char c )
{
    char *tmp = new char[top + 2];
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < top; i++ ) tmp[i] = stack[i];
    
    delete [] stack;
    
    stack = tmp;
    
    stack[top] = c;
    stack[++top] = '\0';
}

int main() 
{
    const char *p = "([]}";
    char *stack = new char[1] { '\0' };
    
    for ( const char *tmp = p; *tmp; ++tmp ) push( stack, *tmp );
    
    std::cout << std::strlen( stack ) << '\n';
    std::cout << stack << '\n';
    
    delete [] stack;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
4
([]}
```